# Android NDK overriding methods

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have 2 NDK libraries (`.so` files ) in my android project and there is a method in the first library that is also called (used) in the first library and I want the second library to override the called (used)  method found in the first library. Is it possible to just have the same name and parameters and load the second library after the first like

```
System.load(first);
System.load(second);
```

Will this override the first method or do I have to do something else? If so, please specify.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Once a symbol has been resolved (by `System.load`) it will not be changed. The definition loaded from `first` will be used.